# need to know how many students in each city from studentsDB statics page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding the statistics page PHP&MYSQL, I have cities table ( id, cityname) and students table in database content(id, name, cityname, phone , class)
Now I want to show number of students in each city like this ex :

```
city1 = 51 students 
city2 = 150 students 
city3 = 32 students 
.
. 
city50 = 550 students
```

This function is work well and return students in a city given :

```
<?php
$students = get_students_by_cityname("city1");
if($students == NULL)
    die("Problem ..");

$scount = count($students);
if($scount == 0)
    die("No students ..");

echo "city1 has $scount students";

?>
```

I have 50 cities must I repeat this function 50 time !!!

I tried to use loops but not work please I really need helps!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have permission to create SQL `group by` query, try this code: (It's better to get your output by `group by` statement)

```
$cities = array('city1', 'city2', ..., 'city50');
$output = array();
foreach($cities as $city){
    $output[$city] = count(get_students_by_cityname($city));
}

foreach($output as $city => $count){
    echo "$city = $count students";
}
```

Comment: friend can I use this !! select cityname, count(*)
from students
group by cityname
order by cityname;

Comment: @AlgeriaProgrammer yes, you can execute this query: `SELECT cityname, count(*) as studentcount FROM students GROUP BY cityname ORDER BY cityname;`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a students table, why not just do a single query?

```
select cityname, count(*)
from students
group by cityname
order by cityname;
```

Comment: I didnt understand??